# how can i associate the headings of columns/rows with content of itself and then recall what i want after i've imported the excel file in mathematica

Tags: import, associations, excel

[image]

Hello, i make another try... I have to import a file like this below (it is an excel file, i show you just the beginnig. it should have thousend of rows and columns). After i've imported the file i need to find a way to recall a specific number or a specific sector. For example if i want to know the value of Agricolture in EE region (EE is an abreviation for "Europe", it is not a costant).Until now i've tried to create an association with the headings and the content of the column/rows , but with any particular result.
I hope i've been clear.
Thanks

Update:
I've imported a .txt file

```
{{"", "", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE"}, {"", "", "Agriculture", 
  "Forestry", "Fishing", "Mining ", "Extraction "}, {"EE", 
  "Agriculture", "0,131346361", "0,01587348", "0,003638642", 
  "8,36E-004", "1,67E-004"}, {"EE", "Forestry", "5,52E-004", 
  "0,155865778", "4,38E-005", "6,00E-004", "4,00E-005"}, {"EE", 
  "Fishing", "2,33E-004", "4,04E-005", "0,024580636", "4,60E-006", 
  "3,76E-006"}, {"EE", "Mining ", "5,71E-004", "2,78E-004", 
  "5,12E-005", "0,034537603", "3,69E-005"}, {"EE", "Extraction ", 
  "3,67E-004", "2,51E-004", "7,46E-004", "0,001576707", 
  "0,043538054"}}
```

Then i take the headings of the row `csv[[All, 1 ;; 2]]`, do the same for the columns, and i've taken te data`csv[[3 ;;, 3 ;;]]`

I try to create the association

```
md = AssociationThread[r1 -> (AssociationThread[c1 -> #] & /@ d)]
```

and it works if i want to recall a row by writing the i,j position of the cell or writing the position of the row... but if i write the name of the Headings it doesn't work

Comment: Have you looked at [Dataset](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) and [AssociationThread](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html) in the documentation.  Can you post the code you've tried thus far.

Comment: Also, it would help if you posted a bit of example data instead of an image. Either make an Excel file with some representative example data (i.e. have unique row labels) and post the results of the import.

Comment: data1 = Drop[
   Join@Import[
     "C:\\Users\\Andrea\\Desktop\\three_region_60_sector_iot.xls", \
{"Sheets", "iot"}], {1, 2}, {1, 2}] // TableForm  (whit this command i've imported the data without the headings)    , the i've used  alfa = Import[
  "C:\\Users\\Andrea\\Desktop\\three_region_60_sector_iot.xls", \
{"Sheets", "iot"}]  and then  headers = Join@Take[alfa, {3, 180}, {1, 2}]   (so i've taken the headings )....in the end i've tried   io = Association@Thread[Rule[headers, data1]]....but in this case ii doesn't work as i would

Comment: Edit the question and post the output from `alfa[[ 1 ;; 10 , 1 ;; 10 ]]`. This will give a starting point for people so that they don't have to create a dataset to work on.  If the data is sensitive then make up a dummy set of data in Excel, import it and post the result.

Comment: sorry...i'm having problems about posting what i need because i'm not an expert user

Comment: just use the "edit" link below your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the code for an example table (please provide copyable example data next time you post a question):

```
m= {{"", "", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE"}, 
    {"", "", "Agriculture", "Forestry", "Fishing", "Mining", "Extraction"}, 
    {"EE", "Agriculture", 5.5646, 1.08922, 7.83459, 7.37088, 4.69533}, 
    {"EE", "Forestry", 7.02039, 0.839213, 4.81989, 6.74534, 3.58382}, 
    {"EE", "Fishing", 8.73866, 7.30894, 1.43181, 0.28529, 5.02924}, 
    {"EE", "Mining", 1.21729, 3.79903, 9.72889, 9.60559, 2.55934}, 
    {"EE", "Extraction", 7.13465, 5.61534, 4.93024, 0.765702, 4.18025}}
```

You have column and row names the same. That's rather confusing, but I'll leave it that way. I'm not sure what you want to do with the EE parts so I won't use them. Let's separate names and data:

```
colNames = m[[2, 3;;]];
rowNames = m[[3;;, 2]];
data = m[[3;;, 3;;]];
```

Now, we're going to make a `Dataset` with named columns *and* rows. We need an Association of Associations for that:

```
mds = AssociationThread[rowNames -> (AssociationThread[colNames -> #] & /@ data)]//Dataset
```

[image]

Extracting various parts from that (it's a Dataset, so we are allowed to use single brackets):

```
mds[1, 1]
(* 5.5646 *)

mds["Agriculture"]
```

[image]

```
mds[2 ;; 4, "Fishing"]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

It seems that you want to address the data with two names for both the rows and the columns. In that case you have to do it slightly different. You could either combine the name strings into a single "EE Agriculture" or use a list of those names {"EE", "Agriculture"}.

Approach 1:

We make a list of pairs of names:

```
colNames = m[[{1, 2}, 3 ;;]]\[Transpose]
rowNames = m[[3 ;;, {1, 2}]]
data = m[[3 ;;, 3 ;;]];

(*{{"EE", "Agriculture"}, {"EE", "Forestry"}, {"EE", "Fishing"}, {"EE", 
  "Mining"}, {"EE", "Extraction"}}

{{"EE", "Agriculture"}, {"EE", "Forestry"}, {"EE", "Fishing"}, {"EE", 
  "Mining"}, {"EE", "Extraction"}}*)

mds = AssociationThread[rowNames -> (AssociationThread[colNames -> #] & /@ data)]//Dataset;
```

Because we don't have strings as keys anymore, but instead pairs of strings, we now need `Key` as the reference:

```
 mds[Key[{"EE", "Agriculture"}], Key[{"EE", "Fishing"}]]
(* 7.83459 *)

mds[Key[{"EE", "Agriculture"}], 2 ;; 4] // Normal
(*<|{"EE", "Forestry"} -> 1.08922, {"EE", "Fishing"} -> .83459, 
  {"EE", "Mining"} -> 7.37088|>  *)
```

Approach 2 (combine strings):

```
colNames = m[[{1, 2}, 3 ;;]]\[Transpose]
rowNames = m[[3 ;;, {1, 2}]]
data = m[[3 ;;, 3 ;;]];

colNames = ToString[#1] <> " " <> ToString[#2] & @@@ colNames
rowNames = ToString[#1] <> " " <> ToString[#2] & @@@ rowNames;
(* {"EE Agriculture", "EE Forestry", "EE Fishing", "EE Mining", "EE Extraction"} *)

mds = AssociationThread[rowNames -> (AssociationThread[colNames -> #] & /@ data)]//Dataset
```

[image]

```
mds["EE Agriculture", "EE Fishing"]
(* 7.83459 *)
```

---

**Update 2**

Andrea: exactly copy and paste the code below. Do not change anything and check whether this works:

```
m = {{"", "", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE"}, {"", "", "Agriculture", 
   "Forestry", "Fishing", "Mining", "Extraction"}, {"EE", 
   "Agriculture", 5.5646`, 1.08922`, 7.83459`, 7.37088`, 
   4.69533`}, {"EE", "Forestry", 7.02039`, 0.839213`, 4.81989`, 
   6.74534`, 3.58382`}, {"EE", "Fishing", 8.73866`, 7.30894`, 
   1.43181`, 0.28529`, 5.02924`}, {"EE", "Mining", 1.21729`, 3.79903`,
    9.72889`, 9.60559`, 2.55934`}, {"EE", "Extraction", 7.13465`, 
   5.61534`, 4.93024`, 0.765702`, 4.18025`}}; colNames = 
 Transpose[m[[{1, 2}, 3 ;; All]]]; rowNames = 
 m[[3 ;; All, {1, 2}]]; data = m[[3 ;; All, 3 ;; All]]; colNames = 
 Apply[ToString[#1] <> " " <> ToString[#2] &, 
  colNames, {1}]; rowNames = 
 Apply[ToString[#1] <> " " <> ToString[#2] &, rowNames, {1}]; mds = 
 Dataset[AssociationThread[
   rowNames -> (AssociationThread[colNames -> #1] &) /@ data]]
```

Comment: Sorry if I've created in you these problems..i will try your method and then i'll tell you if it works. The issue about the same name of rows and columns it is because this is a matrix called Input-Output table ..it needs double entries

Comment: No..it doesn't work

Comment: Firstable...which kind of import did you do?

Comment: I' ve make a try with your example , but it is wrong

Comment: @andrea See update. You made an error by using code meant for single rows of names and applying that unmodified to double rows of names.

Comment: When i try the first method it doesn't work because the output of the association doesn't outfit like your table..i don't know why (I've to try more times and then i tell you)...The second one works quite good..it is reallt near what i need (do you think after i take for example a row it is possible to change the values and mantainig the same asset?) @Sjoerd C. de Vries

Comment: Do you think this is the maximum level about extracting from a matrix a specific Matrix?

Comment: @andrea I copied approach 1 and 2 in the wrong order from my notebook. Corrected now. Check it out.

Comment: I think i keep doing the same mistake when i try the 2nd approach: labels's output in my excercise are" "EEAgriculture", "EEFishing",..." and then the Dataset has no columns but just rows:                                                                   {
 {"EEAgriculture", <|"EEAgriculture" -> "0,131346361", 
   "EEForestry" -> "0,01587348", "EEFishing" -> "0,003638642", 
   "EEMining " -> "8,36E-004", 
   "EEExtraction " -> "1,67E-004"|>}
}

Comment: @andrea Have you copied my code verbatim  or have you changed it in any way?

Comment: i've just written down in mathematica..not copied

Comment: I guess you have made a transcription error then.

Comment: i'm sure i didn't..i tried several times

Comment: @andrea I collected all the necessary code for approach 2 in one box in the answer above (Update 2). Just copy and paste it and start it on a clean, fresh kernel. I tried it and it really works for me.